# Getting "No such commands sip reload"

Tags: sip, sip-server, opensips

I configured sip.conf and extensions.conf files, I am Able to reload the dialplan but whenever I type sip reload, sip show users or sip show peers, I am getting no such commands, type 'core sip show help sip reload',...

Comment: There are millions of asterisk (and assume it is asterisk) sites that can help you with these types of problems. Google is your friend

Answer (score 0):

Recompile asterisk with channel "chan_sip".